# How do I add or rename $Comment property for xpage or custom control

Tags: xpages

In version 9.0.1fp4, when creating a new XPage or Custom Control you have the option of adding a comment.  It then creates a Properties field, "$Comment" which is attached to the element.  I can't find a way, using Designer, to modify that field after creating it.  I'm pretty sure there's a programmatic way to get to the field, but I'm just looking for a simple way of changing. Rename will change the element name, but not give access to $Comment.

Answer (score 1):

It's awkward, but you can edit it from the XPage or CC list. Position the cursor at the start of the non-demarcated Comments column (just below the left edge of the "C" in the header), click, and wait a few seconds.